# Swift: Scrollview with 2 pages

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, mkmapview

I have been struggling a bit with this: I need a UIScrollView with 2 pages(horizontal, paging enabled). When the viewcontroller loads i need to show some information(labels, mostly) and then if you swipe to the right i need to display a MapView. If you then scroll to the left you see the labels again. What is the best way to create this?

Currently i have a UIScrollView with the width of the ViewController. Do i need to create 2 seperate .xib files, one for each page? And then load the xib files in the UIScrollView? Can someone point me in the right direction to create this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the help of two `UIViews`/`XIBs`, you have to set the `pagingEnabled` property of `UIScrollView` to `true` which does not let the `UIScrollView` to stop in between two `UIViews`.

Set the frame of your `UIView`s in such a way that they appear as pages in whole screen. Below is an example I just coded. And also set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView`. For better understanding see the code below

```
//Create a frame with size of the parent frame(fullscreen)
var firstFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame;

//this frame will be used for content size of UIScrollView
var bigFrame : CGRect = firstFrame

//since you need two views of full screen width, set the width of this frame as twice
bigFrame.size.width *= 2.0

//Create scrollview with frame "firstFrame" 
var scrollView : UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: firstFrame)
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

var firstView : UIView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
scrollView.addSubview(firstView)
firstFrame.origin.x = yourFirstView.frame.size.width
var secondView : UIView = UIView(frame: firstFrame)
scrollView.addSubview(secondView)
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
scrollView.contentSize = bigFrame.size
```